# How to get Unicode in code listings?

Tags: listings, unicode, listingsutf8

I want to use Unicode text (a mixture of cyrillic and japanese characters) in a code listing that uses default LaTeX fonts (in other words, source code fonts are left to default). However, for all non-ASCII characters I get empty spaces instead.

I've tried adding the `utf8` package, but to no avail. How can I get the Unicode characters to show up?

Comment: The question is tagged with [tag:listingsutf8], have you tried this package after reading its documentation?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I have tried listingutf8 but the text still doesn't shot up :(

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk The characters must fit in an 8-bit encoding. Cyrillic characters could work, but a mixture of Cyrillic and Japanese characters are likely not fit into an 8-bit encoding.